# not recognizing exported class method

Tags: dllexport

My code:

```
 HINSTANCE hdll =     LoadLibrary(L"D:\\MyDLL\\Debug\\Mydll.dll");

if (!hDLL) {
std::cout << "could not load dll" << std::endl;
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}   

EntryPointfuncPtr test;
test = (EntryPointfuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"create");
test();
```

My test() crashes here as the create() is name mangled..I use the name mangled name eg ?create@@ it works fine...

PLZ tell where have I gon wrong..

I have exported a class in a dll

Comment: `LoadLibrary(L"D:\\MyDLL\\Debug\\Mydll.dll");` no `,` betwwen `L` and path?

Comment: no comma...that is fine...I am basically struggling with name mangling...how to avoid that..and also create() is a static method inside the class

Comment: NOte: my dll is loaded, it just thatGetProc is failing